# Selenium: Error selecting option of a select dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium with python. I don't know why when I try to select an option of a select dynamically I've got an error. These are my code:

```
select_season = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("_ctl0:temporadasDropDownList"))
select_season.select_by_value("2015")
```

These code work fine but If I change "2015" by the value get it from a variable or a list I've got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/main.py", line 104, in
>   
>       main()   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/main.py", line 94, in main
>       FEBDocument(data)   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/parsers/feb/document/bx_document.py",
>   line 21, in **init**
>       self.load_all_competitions(driver, data)   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/parsers/feb/document/bx_document.py",
>   line 114, in load_all_competitions
>       select_season.select_by_value(data["season"])   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py",
>   line 79, in select_by_value
>       opts = self._el.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>   line 685, in find_elements
>       {"using": by, "value": value})['value']   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>   line 633, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/europa/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given
>   css selector expression "option[value ="2015 "]" is invalid:
>   SyntaxError: 'option[value ="2015 "]' is not a valid selector

And the code from I get this error is:

```
select_season = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("_ctl0:temporadasDropDownList"))
select_season.select_by_value(data["season"])
```

How can I select dynamically an option from a select with python and selenium?

Comment: Where are you getting `data["season"]` from?

Comment: Returns: 2015. It's a value retrieved from a file

Comment: The only difference that I see is that there's a space after the 5: `"2015 "`

Comment: When hard coding a value works but a variable's value doesn't... the first thing you should do is to look at what's in that variable... is it the right value? is it the right type? and so on. Learning to debug your own code is a valuable skill and will save you a LOT of time.